# How do I highlight class Variables in Sub-Class within Visual Studio Editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editor, subclass

I don't post very often and I have tried to do my research but simply cannot find if my wish is possible using the Visual Studio 2017 Community Editor.  I an entry level just-for-fun programmer of C# and am now learning about sub-classes.  Here is my wish (and question):

I have developed a class in a separate file (class Parent).  It is a very simple class with some public variables.  Now in a separate file I have another sub-class Child based of Parent (class Child:Parent).  Within the class Child, I use the variables of Parent which are available to me in Child.  Everything fine and the compiler doesn't flag my code for errors.  So, good or bad, right or wrong, I'm getting the hang of classes and sub-classes.

My wish for the Visual Studio editor is when I look at some variables in my Child class, I find myself wondering, where did those variables come from?  Where were they defined? Then I have my ah-a moment and remember they are coming from the Parent class.  If I "peek definition' the code, everything is revealed to me very nicely.

But my question to you is can Visual Studio editor somehow colorize these variables that are used in the sub-class but defined in parent class?  Especially when the Parent class for me is in another file which is not currently opened?

Just a wish...otherwise what I have is fine but it would be nice when looking at my code after a long time to just see these variables originating from a parent class in another color perhaps.

I did try to go through the Font-Color settings but honestly was overwhelmed and couldn't find a direct hit there.

Any help or comments on this very low priority question would be welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is an option like that. I have never seen or even considered the possibility of colouring members declared in the super class a different color. I think the truth is, you don't need it. When I now see a new variable I will look at its name and figure out what it's for. As long as the compiler doesn't complain, the variable is probably declared _somehwere_.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a Rosyln Analyzer. Its not trivial to do, but easiser than previous ways to extend VS.

Comment: Thank you Crowcoder for your comment.  I have never heard of a Rosyln Analyzer but I will research it.  I appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a feature in VS, you don't need it anyway. According to Crowcoder in the comments, this can be done by writing a Roslyn Analyzer, but I don't think you should do this just because you want to know where are the variables declared. Trust me, you don't need it.

The truth is, in most cases you are not the one who should worry about where exactly a variable is declared when you are reading code. That's the job of the compiler.

If your variables and classes are well-named, you will be able to understand immediately, without thinking about "Wait where does this come from?". For example:

```
class Slime: Monster {
    public Slime() {
        Health = 10;
    }
}
```

Given that this code compiles successfully, do you need to worry about where `Health` is defined? No! It's a slime! Obviously it's gonna have a `Health`. Do you need to check out the definition to see what it is used for? No! From the name, we can clearly see that it represents how much health is left for the slime.

Basically, what I mean is that if you can write code with well named variables, you will be able to figure out what each variable does without looking at the definition.

Comment: Thank you so much Sweeper for your answer to my question.  Now I can understand exactly what you mean.  It was this sentence that brought it home for me: "you are not the one who should worry about where exactly a variable is declared when you are reading code. That's the job of the compiler.".  You know maybe it is because I'm a beginner that I just wanted to know everything about my code (which honestly I hadn't looked at in a few months).  But you are right...when reviewing code, if the compiler doesn't balk it is part of the class and that is all I need to know.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Just hovering the mouse over a member variable tells you where it is declared, e.g. if in a sublcass of X and hovering over 'foo' which is an integer declared in X, it will show you `int X.foo`. It's not exactly what you ask, which as others commented is not easy to get, but it's by far the easiest way and doesn't require Peek Definition.

Comment: Wow...you are not going to be believe this but honestly I had no idea about this feature.  I mean I see all sorts of pop-up tips appear and there but never really stopped to look at what was appearing.  Forgive me as I am still new and mostly this is just a hobby at this point.  I did as you suggested and indeed I could see the definition and also showing the parent class in the pop-up tip.  All without needing to "Peek".  Thank you.